# Getting error during ogg to mp3 conversion

Tags: php, angularjs, ffmpeg, audio-recording, ogg

I used RecordRTC and implemented with Angular.js, audio recording is working fine in Mozilla and recorded blob type is ogg, so I saving file in server in ogg format.

But I need it in MP3 format as we have to support in different phone OS. So I further converting using ffmpeg:

> `exec('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/dtswork/bluejaypt/us/bjaypt/uploads/index.ogg -acodec libmp3lame  /var/www/dtswork/bluejaypt/us/bjaypt/uploads/index.mp3 2>&1'))`

Using above command but it's giving  "/var/www/dtswork/bluejaypt/us/bjaypt/uploads/index.ogg: End of file".

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the ogg file is reachable, has the correct contents, is readable, etc...?

Comment: no i did not check that, can you tell me how to check that, but file is playing fine in web using audio tag

Answer (score 1):

Wow look this!

install opus-tools (with libopus) like on debian-based

```
sudo aptitude install lib-opus 

opusdec file.ogg file.wav

ffmpeg -i file.wav file.mp3
```

works well

also I think will help recompile the last ffmpeg. but i didn't have enough time for this.

by the way do you have any glitches during recording?

Comment: i checked the audio file is playing in vlc and html5 audio fine, but can you tell me how to check if have any glitches on ogg

Comment: in my variant i have no sound at 20-21 sec.

Comment: is my solution helped?

Answer (score 0):

Is your file correctly uploaded? Have you tried to download it and listen?
Try e.g. `exec('ffmpeg -i old_file.ogg -ar 22050 new_file.mp3')`.

Comment: I'm convert random ogg and everything is fine. i need some time for recording smth. with RecordRTC. Or you can send ogg sample file to me.

Comment: Hi, @Matvey , here is a dummy link of ogg that i recorded  http://59.162.181.92/dtswork/bluejaypt/us/bjaypt/uploads/chataudio_50_1421165806.ogg

Comment: what browser you using. Mozilla 34?

Comment: Yes @Matvey, using mozilla34

Comment: Hi @Matvey, can you please guide me how to use vorbis codec